# How to use same directive multiple times with parent in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I've got following script

```
// Code goes here

angular.module('default', [])
  .directive('webAbc', function($log) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
        this.checkboxes             = [];
        this.updateLinkedCheckboxes = function(value) {
          angular.forEach(this.checkboxes, function(checkbox, index) {
            checkbox.setChecked(value);
          });
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('webDef', function($log) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      require: '^webAbc',
      link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, webAbc, transcludeFn) {
        iElement.bind('change', function () {
          webAbc.updateLinkedCheckboxes(iElement.prop('checked'));
          scope.$apply();
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('webGhi', function($log) {
    return {
      restict: 'A',
      require: '^webAbc',
      link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, webAbc, transcludeFn) {
        scope.setChecked = function(value) {
          $log.log('This element ' + iAttrs.name + ' cheked: ' + (!value ? 'checked' : ''));
          $log.log(value);
          if (value)
          {
            iElement.attr('checked', 'checked');
          }
          else
          {
            iElement.remoteAttr('checked');
          }
        };

        webAbc.checkboxes.push(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

it should select or deselect all checkboxes in table in marked column, but I can't make it work with following solution.

First of all it seems, that only last `webGhi` is visible due to print out in console. And even more, it seems, that I can't uncheck checkbox for some reason.

Link to an example: http://jsbin.com/difihabe/1/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an isolated scope in the `webGhi` directive or all four instances of it will push the same scope (the parent):

```
.directive('webGhi', function($log) {
  return {
    restict: 'A',
    require: '^webAbc',
    scope: {},
    link: ...
```

Also instead of adding/removing the checked attribute either use:

1. jQuery's `prop()` function: `iElement.prop('checked', value);`
2. Directly setting the DOM element's checked property:
   `iElement[0].checked = value;`

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/tudotugi/2/

Comment: This is great. Thank you. To clear things up, if no local scope defined, then last element will overwrite it for all of them and therefore only it will be used, correct? And settings local scope will make each of the rows unique, correct?

Comment: All four instances of the directive will use the same scope (the parent). `webAbc.checkboxes.push(scope);` will be called four times, which means there will be four references to the parent scope in the array. All four instances will define `scope.setChecked = function(value)` on the same scope. This means that all four references in the array will have the `setChecked` defined by the last of the four as it will overwrite the others. As the `setChecked` function contains a referece to `iElement` of the fourth instance of the directive, this is the one working (semi-working) in your example.